# Overcoming Windows User Object Handle Limit

Tags: user-interface, winapi, swt

I'm looking for advanced strategies for dealing with User Object Handle limits when building heavy-weight windows interfaces.  Please explain how you overcame or bypassed this issue using SWT or direct Windows GUI APIs.  The only thing I am not interested in is strategies to optimize widget usage as I have done this extensively and it does not solve the problem, only makes it less likely.

My Situation:
I have an SWT based GUI that allows for multiple sessions within the same parent shell and within each session their are 3 separate places where a list of user generated comments are displayed.  As a user opens multiple sessions and pulls data that populates those lists, the number of user object handles can increase dramatically depending on the number of comments.

My current solutions:
1. I page the comments by default thereby limiting the number of comment rows in each session, but due to management demands, i also have what is effectively a "View All" button which bypasses this completely.
2. I custom draw all non-editable information in each row.  This means each row utilizes only 2 object handles.
3. I created JNI calls which query the OS for the current usage and the Max usage.  With this i can give indications to users that a crash is imminent.  Needless to say, they ignore this warning.

Comment: Hey, Spencer, how did you implement solution 3?

Answer (score 7):

First off, are you sure the problem isn't desktop heap vs. handle count? Each handle can consume a certain amount of Windows desktop heap. One USER handle may eat a lot of space, some very little. I'm suggesting this to make sure you're not chasing user handle counts when it's really something else. (google for Microsoft's dheapmon tool, it may help)

I've read that you can alter the maxes on handles by changing keys in the registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\
     CurrentVersion\Windows\ **USERProcessHandleQuota** and **GDIProcessHandleQuota**

This could be a short term fix for users.

I'd approach this by first figuring out what 2 user handles need to be maintained for each item (like 2 for each item in a listbox?). This seems suspect. [User handles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725486.aspx) are for only a few top-level Windows UI objects (Windows, menus, cursors, Window positions, ***icons***, etc...). I don't see why your widget needs to keep 2 objects around for each item (is it an icon handle??).

**If you're looking to rip the whole thing apart - this sounds like a job for a [virtual-mode List-View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774735(VS.85).aspx) (LVS_OWNERDATA).**

Answer (score 5):

You should think about using windowless controls. They are designed for precisely this situation. See ["Windowless controls are not magic"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050211-00/?p=36473), by Raymond Chen

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that he is creating multiple (1000's) of windows that eat up handles. It sounds as if his single (or is it 3) windows are eating 2 handles per "item" they display.

Comment: It was hard to tell from the original question, but you could be right

Answer (score 2):

Not only top-level windows, but most native controls use one user object each. See [Give Me a Handle, and I'll Show You an Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810501.aspx) for an in-depth explanation of user- and other handle types. This also means that SWT uses at least one user handle per widget, even for a Composite.

If you truly are hitting the limit of 10000 user objects per process, and you don't have a leak, then your only option is to reduce the number of widget instances in your application. I wrote a [blog article](http://www.subshell.com/en/subshell/blog/index.html) about how we did this for our application.