# SWT - How to debug "No more handles"

Tags: java, windows, swt, handles

from time to time I am haunted by the "org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles". I already know tools like GDIView, to watch the number of handles allocated, but now I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

Is there a tool available? Maybe one that logs all stacktraces when handles are created? And which shows the new handles between two invocation points?

Regards,
Daniel

PS: Added the windows tag because dev occures mostly on windows and a windows only tool would be good enough.

Comment: This question may be related to your inquiry:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164776/overcoming-windows-user-object-handle-limit

Comment: @Zoot: He seems to work on the symptoms, not the cause. I am just looking for the real leaks, I don't really need many handles. It is that just over time there are too many resources used. By using sleak I was even able to look for recreated resources. Debugging  this also makes my app noticable faster over RDP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out about [Sleak](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/tools.php), a great tool to debug SWT resources! Highly recommended for everyone with the same problems. Even shows the images for image resources!

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was simply that new Shell() has been called too often. Storing the shell as static member and reusing it helped. Therefore, before applying a tool like Sleak, others might want to do a full text search for "new Shell" and check that they don't have the same simple cause.

Answer (score 0):

Sleak seems to be very outdated and I did not get it working.
Eventually this will also help someone. Add the following code early in your ui code:

```
Display.getCurrent().DEBUG = true;
Display.getCurrent().setTracking(true);
```

Output on close/dispose of the application:

```
Summary: 930 Font(s), 50 Image(s)
```

Also a list with stacktraces is outputed with places where resources was allocated.

See Device class source code for further details: https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/blob/7479681ce2cd75b1adb10220d061d83e4f83e2cd/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT/cocoa/org/eclipse/swt/graphics/Device.java